# Nested loop with Underscore.js to populate dropdown with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js

We need to populate a dropdown containing countries and if Locales are present in respecitve country then populate one more dropdown using underscore template.

```
var countrySelectorTemplate = '<select class="form-control"><% _.each(resultsData.Countries, function(results) { %> <option><%= results.CountryName %></option> <% } ) %></select>';
```

JSON is available on http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/4NbGL/

As of now, it populates the select dropdown with countries. How can i put nested condition  to populate one more dropdown if locales are present for respective country?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
var countrySelectorTemplate = '<select class="form-control"><% _.each(resultsData.Countries, function(results) { %> <option><%= results.CountryName %></option> <% if ("Locales" in results) { %> "Another Dropdown" <% }<% } ) %></select>';
```